# Excel: Allocating Streams to Students based on GPA and Choice Preference

Tags: excel

I have a total of 64 students to be allocated to 19 different streams on the basis of their GPA. Students have also indicated their preference for the streams. Only 5 students can be allocated to first three streams (A-C), 4 students to Stream D and the remaining fifteen streams get 3 students each. I have added the data to an excel sheet but have no idea how to process that to achieve the above results. [The data is organized like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKzVU.png). I'm happy to share the original file but couldn't find way to upload that.

Comment: try [this](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for uploading data arrays for questions ( also works for parsing back into tab or comma-delimited )

Comment: If this is a one off I would sort by GPA and allocate the streams by hand. If you're doing it for the challenge or if you have a need to work with large data sets or many data sets, hopefully someone else has the time to give an actual technical solution.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to do it manually but there are more number of students in some cases that gave first preference to a particular stream than the available positions and it needs to consider their 2nd, 3rd even 7th preference and that becomes complicated for manual allocation.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved automatically in a vba macro but the slightly faster version is doing it a bit fast and dirty with formulas. It starts like you have already, ranking by gpa.

Insert 2 rows for each student. In this row you will calculate the "filling" of the streams. If you have a bazillion students, you should write a small macro to copy paste so you get every other line. A shame that excel does not accept pasting empty values as no-change-values.

Either change the rankings by search/replace or create a new sheet where the "desired allocation" value is HIGHEST for the MOST WANTED stream. 
Cell C2 should be like this:

```
 =20-'originalsheet'!C2
```

We are now working on the new sheet

So you have these rows: (student - allocation - availability - student - allocation - availability)

In the allocation line, you will fill the allocation of the student above, in the availability row you will fill the current available spaces.

The first student gets allocated to his or hers choice.

The allocation row gets a formula that investigates if the current cell has the lowest possible value. So. Row2: first student, Row3: Allocation, Row4: new availability, Row5: Students wishes, Row 6: We use this formula in cell C6

```
=if(sumproduct(max(($C5:$U5)*(($C4:$U4)>0)))=C6;1;0)
```

Then the next line, new availability is simply

```
=C4-C6
```

copy paste the formulas downwards. You may get trouble with students on exactly similar GPAs but your ranking from top to bottom is what sets the priority in this scheme. I don't have the original file and I don't have time to build it from an image but it looked like it worked for my tiny test-setup.

Slightly easier than doing it by hand, but again; if you have a bazillion students and are doing this allocation often - ask in the vba section.

Summary:

1. Rank by GPA
2. Change so highest wish is highest number
3. Insert 2 rows for each student
4. Calculate manually for first student, should not be difficult...
5. Use formulas and make certain the cell references are not bungled up.